# Passing argument 4 of 'objc_setProperty' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: objective-c, properties

I am getting this warning on the following line:

```
@synthesize labels;
```

Now, the rest of my declaration (in the `.h` file) is as follows:

```
@interface Menus:SuperClass<Protocols>
{
    ...    
    UILabel **labels;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel             **labels;
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `retain` property only works with class-type objects (i.e. pointers to `objc_object`). The generated setters would e.g. attempt to call `-retain` on the argument it gets, which obviously doesn't work on a pointer-to-pointer.

You could preferably use a container like `NSArray` instead. If you want to go with the quite atypical dynamic C-style array for some reason you could use an `assign` property.

Comment: I'd go further and say that `UILabels **` is an extremely atypical pattern.  Why not an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: @bbum: Right, i reworded that somewhat to not give the wrong impression.